# Inside loop showing getAttribute(String) is undefined

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently, I am trying to get breadcrumb name and link from a website.I am writing code for getting breadcrumb name and its working perfectly but Inside loop when I try to get the breadcrumb link its show me an error.

> The method getAttribute(String) is undefined for the type List

**Html Code is here**

```
<div class="breadCrumb listView" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
     <div itemscope="" itemprop="itemListElement" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
        <span class="separator">/</span>
        <a href="https://www.flipkey.com/" itemprop="item">
           <span itemprop="name">Home</span>
        </a>
     </div>
     <div itemscope="" itemprop="itemListElement" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
         <span class="separator">/</span>
         <a href="https://www.flipkey.com/vacation-rentals" itemprop="item">
            <span itemprop="name">Vacation Rentals</span>
         </a>
      </div>
      <div itemscope="" itemprop="itemListElement" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
          <span class="separator">/</span> 
             <a href="https://www.flipkey.com/united-states-vacation-rentals/g191/" itemprop="item">
               <span itemprop="name">United States</span>
              </a>
      </div>
      <div itemscope="" itemprop="itemListElement" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
          <span class="separator">/</span>
          <a href="https://www.flipkey.com/florida-vacation-rentals/g28930/" itemprop="item">
               <span itemprop="name">Florida</span>
          </a>
      </div>
 </div>
```

**Here is my Code**

```
   List<WebElement> Breadcrumblist=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='breadCrumb listView']/div/a/span"));
   List<WebElement>  crumblink=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='breadCrumb listView']/div/a"));
   for (WebElement Breadcrumb:Breadcrumblist ){
                  
       String count=Breadcrumb.getText();
                   
       String Crumblinktext=crumblink.getAttribute("href");
                   System.setOut(myconsole);
       myconsole.print(""+count+">");
       myconsole.print(""+Crumblinktext+",");
                            
                   
     }
```

Error showing here

> String Crumblink=crumblink.getAttribute("href");
>
> getAttribute(String) is undefined

Not understand why this error showing.Any type of suggesting will appreciated.

Comment: `crumblink` is a list. Did you mean `Breadcrumb.getAttribute("href");`?

Comment: yes when I add this line its show me error get attribute(String) is undefined

Comment: Your line is `crumblink.getAttribute("href");`. It should be `Breadcrumb.getAttribute("href")`.

Comment: Basically, i want to take breadcrumb name and link and show it separate

Comment: A list crumblink would not have the getAttribute method associated with it.

Comment: Can you please take a look at HTML code

Comment: @zsbappa You have your answer. `crumblink.getAttribute("href");` should be `Breadcrumb.getAttribute("href")`.

Comment: I already edit this and still, i have same problem

Comment: @zsbappa Please post the current code. If you edited it you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: List<WebElement>  crumblink=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='breadCrumb listView']/diva"));

String Crumblinktext=crumblink.getAttribute("href");

I have problem with this two line

Comment: please check my answer it may be helpful for your requirement.

Comment: @zsbappa You didn't change anything.

Comment: Thanks, Guy My problem is solved by @murthi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be your requirement.

```
List<WebElement>  crumblink=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='breadCrumb listView']/div/a"));
for (WebElement Breadcrumb:crumblink){
    String count=Breadcrumb.findElement(By.tagName("span")).getText();
    String Crumblinktext=Breadcrumb.getAttribute("href");
    System.setOut(myconsole);
    myconsole.print(""+count+">");
    myconsole.print(""+Crumblinktext+",");
 }
```